# Repeating coroutine with delays

Tags: android

I am looking a way to launch a thread that would make a GUI element blink forever, in pseudo-code:

```
while (true) {
  GUI element ON
  wait for 1s
  element OFF
  wait for 1s
}
```

I'm thinking of a recursive chain of handlers, like this:

```
val handler = Handler()
handler.postDelayed({
    Handler().postDelayed({ gui_element_on() }, 1000)
    Handler().postDelayed({ gui_element_off() }, 1000)
    handler.postDelayed(this,0)
}, 1000)
```

Only that this won't work. I don't know how to do it properly. And I am not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: I am not really familliar with kotlin, but why do you use `Handler()` once and `handler` the other time?

Comment: just to save a few extra lines.. `val handler = Handler; handler.postDelayed(..)` is the same as `Handler().postDelayed(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this recursive solution:

```
val handler : Handler = Handler()
val run: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        gui_element_on()
        handler.postDelayed({gui_element_off()}, 1000)
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
    }
}
run.run()
```

It does the trick in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CoroutineScope.launch`
Here, I use `lifecycleScope` extension property from Android Jetpack.

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(...) {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            while(isActive) {
                 GUIElementOn()
                 delay(1000)
                 GUIElementOff()
                 delay(1000)
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems more complicated that what I'd like to. I've found another solution, I'm replying myself. thanks